# Unable to connect to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created AWS ec2 instance and associated to one security group. In the associated security group, i have open up HTTP (HTTP,TCP, 80, 0.0.0.0/0), SSH (SSH, TCP, 22, 0.0.0.0/0) and ICMP(All ICMP,All,N/A,0.0.0.0/0) to all.

But when I try to ping to the instance, it is failed; giving request timeout. 
[Inbound rule setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIk1i.jpg)

Also, connecting to the instance using either PuTTY or openssh is failed too. It is giving connection timeout error.

I am not sure if it is something to do with VPC or subnet setting. Can someone help me to figure out the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Can you connect to your machine at all?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are allowing access in the security groups, route tables and NACLS. 
Make sure you are not behind any proxy.

If you are trying to connect from corporate/office network, the firewall doesn't allow the access to the instance.
So make sure you are not behind any proxy while setting up the connection.

Hope It Helps.. :)

Comment: Thank for hints. Problem is resolved now. It was due to internet gateway was not registered in the route table associated with the VPC. After adding the internet gateway to route table, it is working fine.